# Extracting a component from props.children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, styled-components

I was working on a `Panel` component in ReactJS, and so, idea is to make the basic components available along with the collapse/close functionality. However, I am unable to find any way to extract a component from `this.props.children`.

So here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './PanelHeader';
import Body from './PanelBody';


class Panel extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { open: true };
   }


   render() {
      return (
        <StyledPanel>
          {this.props.children}   <-- Is there a way to extract the Header component here
        </StyledPanel>
      );
   }
}

Object.assign(Panel, 
{
  Header,
  Body
});

export default Panel;
```

So, now the user of this component can do something like:

```
<Panel>
   <Panel.Header>Header text for this panel</Panel.Header>
   <Panel.Body>Body of this panel</Panel.Body>
</Panel>
```

`Header` component contains a toolbar control for collapse and close functionalities. Now I do understand that the user of this component can specify these event handlers, and implement these features. But I want this out of the box. So, `Panel` by default, should be able to collapse everything except the header. So is it possible to extract `Header` component inside the `Panel` from `this.props.children`? If yes, then how?

Also, if I did make this work by:

1. Iterating `this.props.children` until `child.type === Header`
2. Using `React.cloneElement` to assign new props
3. And passing in the new event handlers for these new features.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there some elegant way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: An example of reacstrap's implmentation of that pattern can be found in Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter here: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/tree/master/src

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it as a higher-order component which would take `header` and `body` as parameters. You could pass any header or body, the only restriction would be that header requires an `onOpenChanged` callback `prop`.

Here is a working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y3x0r1mjwv).

Link to [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

```
const Header = (props) =>{
  const { onOpenChanged } = props;
  return <div onClick={onOpenChanged}>Header text for this panel</div>;
}

const Body = () => <div>Body of this panel</div>;

const stylishPanel = (WrappedHeader, WrappedBody) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        isOpen: true
      };
    }
    handleToggleOpen = () => {
      this.setState(({ isOpen }) => ({
        isOpen: !isOpen
      }));
    };
    render() {
      const { isOpen } = this.state;
      // your styled-panel instead of div
      return (
        <div className="super-panel">
          <WrappedHeader onOpenChanged={this.handleToggleOpen} />
          {isOpen && <WrappedBody />}
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
};
const App = () => {
  const SuperPanel = stylishPanel(Header, Body);
  return (
    <div style={styles}>
       <SuperPanel />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to extract a component from `this.props.children`,

try to use **Function as a Child / Render props** pattern.

the pattern is like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    bgcolor: 'red'
  }

  render(){
    <div>
       { this.props.children(this.state.bgcolor)}
    </div>
  }
}

class App exnted Component {
  render(){
    <MyComponent> 
      { bgColor => <Header bgcolor={bgColor} /> }
    </MyComponent>
  }
}
```

See `MyComponent` is just a wrapper that passes a value to its function.
The function as written inside `App` component is just a stateless function/component, an arrow function that returns some **JSX**.

The **HOC pattern** as mantioned above is also a way.

This is a known topic about those 2 patterns. This article might shad some light in case your are not yet sure: https://cdb.reacttraining.com/use-a-render-prop-50de598f11ce